# How to fetch all photos from library

Tags: ios, swift, photos

The code shown below is what i've tried already.What I wish to achieve is to fetch all the photos from the device.Currently only a few are being fetched.How to modify the code so as to load all the images from device?

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()

let collection:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.Moment, subtype: .Any, options: fetchOptions)

if let first_Obj:AnyObject = collection.firstObject
{
    self.assetCollection = first_Obj as! PHAssetCollection
}
```

Comment: you're only looking at the first value in the result. Why not look at all the values in the result? Have you checked the `count`?

Comment: You also are fetching collections when you seem to be interested in assets.

Comment: how can i fetch all the values?? sorry i'm new to this

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Updated David's answer for iOS 10+ & **Swift 4.x/3.x**:

**Request permission from the device to access photos:**

Add the following value to your `info.plist`

> Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

And provide a string that is shown to the user.

**Request all images:**

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
    switch status {
    case .authorized:
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
        print("Found \(allPhotos.count) assets")
    case .denied, .restricted:
        print("Not allowed")
    case .notDetermined:
        // Should not see this when requesting
        print("Not determined yet")
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but it will crash if you don't add "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" to info.plist

Comment: @MrStanev That is actually noted at the top of the answer under "Request permission from the device to access photos"

Comment: @CodeBender Is it possible to fetch with limit? Can we make pagination?

Comment: @Dipang Yes, you can use a combination of sortDescriptors, fetchLimits and a predicate to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

All photos is pretty easy, but you need to ensure that you're authorized first.  Here's some simple code to demonstrate:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
    switch status
    {
    case .Authorized:
        print("Good to proceed")
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: fetchOptions)
        print("Found \(allPhotos.count) images")
    case .Denied, .Restricted:
        print("Not allowed")
    case .NotDetermined:
        print("Not determined yet")
    }
}
```

On my phone this returns 25750 items. On a fresh simulator, this should yield 5 images.

Comment: what is the type of allPhotos??

Comment: If you enter the code, and control-click on the fetchAssetsWithMediaType function, you will see that it is a PHFetchResult.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHFetchResult_Class/index.html